# Efficient Server Socket programming

Tags: sockets, serversocket, asyncsocket

I've implemented an efficient windows server using IO completion ports, and now I need to implement a new, cross platform one - Probably using select

My design in Windows is based on X worker threads that get the messages out of the IO completion port queue, where X is a number dependent on the hardware and project properties.

In linux, however, there is no IO Completion Port.
I'd like to keep my design / use a leader-follower design for accepting or reading from the sockets. 
I've looked around a bit, and it seems select is kinda the only way.

(If I understand correctly, using select is equivalent to using WaitForMultipleObjects)
So my design should be something like:

- Create a thread pool
- All threads wait on a select function, with all client sockets read handles, and the listen socket accept handle.
- When a new socket connects, somehow alert the other threads to update their handles for the select function

Breaking the select to update for a new client seems a bit superficial. Is there a better way?

Can someone point me to an example of an high-performance implementation of a socket server?

Comment: Threads are yucky; why would you do it on unix? Fork a load of processes, either one per connection or pass to each worker the fds it's responsible for. Then do a standard select loop to handle the connections in each worker process. I don't know what an IO Completion Port is, but it can't be as simple and tidy as a traditional select loop..?

Comment: Haven't thought about it... How will the user receive the data read by each process?
I mean, a user of the socket library will need to supply a callback or something - How can a callback be called from a different process

Comment: OK, you need to describe your requirements here. I'm imagining something here like a webserver that's serving a lot of concurrent clients and you want to exploit several processes for performance, but not quite as many as one per connection. As with all things, I assume you've got it working initially with a single process, testing has told you you need more performance, and only after that are you trying something fancy with multiple processes/threads...

Comment: Yes. It's something like a webserver (in a proprietary protocol), but part of a system of multiple high-performance programs. It's not implemented yet - Still in design. This "component" is the network infrastructure that we will use to implement this "webserver". That's why I wanted to implement it as a class. Forking, however, suggests different designs

Comment: Sounds like you could do with reading Beej's sockets tutorial and Stevens' UNP. Design it for a single process first, then speed it up if you find you need to. Only one process should listen; it hands the fds to worker processes, and they do a select loop to handle several connections each; all pretty standard in sockets texts.

Comment: Your classes will be: a SelectManager that runs the loop, implemented with select on unix, WSAEventSelect perhaps on Windows. A Listener that registers with the SelectManager and is called back when there's a connection to accept. Some Connection objects created by the Listener (that in a later implementation can be handed over to other worker processes with WSADuplicateSocket/sendmsg). The Connections register with their process's SelectManager and get readable/writable callbacks from it. That's all you need!

Comment: I'll look into Beej's and Stevens'. By the way - Beej recommends on libevent for cross-platform select